# How to get the xml node inside another node having attribute

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got an xml:

```
<pages>
<page id="1" pagename="mypagename">
 <field>
    <addedbox>
        <label>myname</label>
        <id>myid</id>
    </addedbox>
 </field>    
</page>
</pages>
```

How do I get the value of the label?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Show or tell us what have you tried and what concrete problem do you have as SO is not "write me some code" portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("myxml.xml");
        //XmlNode node = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//pages/page[@id='1'])");
        XmlNode node1 = (xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//pages/page[@id='1']/field/addedbox/label"));
```